# Python - How to convert CSV to XLSX?

Tags: python, csv, export-to-excel

I have a code to convert CSV to XLXS the only problem is that when I do the conversion some numeric columns are stored as text. And that makes SQL unable to convert from nvarchar to float.

Code:

```
import csv, os
from glob import glob
from xlsxwriter.workbook import Workbook
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

for csvfile in glob('FILE.CSV'):

    name = os.path.basename(csvfile).split('.')[-2]
    workbook = Workbook('FILE.xlsx', {'strings_to_numbers': True, 'constant_memory': True})
    worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()


    with open(csvfile, 'r') as f:
        r = csv.reader(f, delimiter=';')
        for row_index, row in enumerate(r):
            for col_index, data in enumerate(row):
                worksheet.write(row_index, col_index, data)
                currency_format = workbook.add_format({'num_format': '$#,##0.00'})

    workbook.close()

    import openpyxl

    ss = openpyxl.load_workbook("file.xlsx")
    # printing the sheet names
    ss_sheet = ss['Sheet1']
    ss_sheet.title = 'plan1'
    ss.save("file.xlsx")

print("-------------------------------------------")
print("   .CSV to .XLSX Conversion Successful")
print("-------------------------------------------")
```

Comment: Please also translate the **title** of your post into English

Comment: Questions here should be written in English. You can post in Portuguese at [Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/).

Comment: Please add a few example rows from your CSV file (in text format) to your question